# Blazor component EventCallback set from CSHTML

Tags: components, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor component in one of my CSHTML pages.  The component has an EventCallback property.
I am getting this compile error:

Error   CS0428  Cannot convert method group 'FileUploaded' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Everything works if I am in a Blazor Page which has the Blazor Component, but chokes when using the component in the Razorpage
[image: Code pic]

Comment: It's a method. You need to use a delegate. Like create a delegate to use that calls/invokes the method you're actually trying to call.

Comment: @Nikki9696 thanks for the tip, let me think about how to do that.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of making an EventHandler of the right type in your model and using that, pretty similar to how the Blazor one did it. Then you just += it in the model ctor to hook them up (and -= in Dispose)

Comment: Thanks, working on it.